# Prevent user from faking GPS location

Tags: gps, geolocation, location

I want to introduce an achievement when a user is at a specific location. Is it possible to check / prevent a user from faking their GPS location?

Swarmapp.com (formerly foursquare) must have done something similar as they had global leaderboards for this kind of thing, all based on user location.

My research has turned up nothing. Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Are you talking about IOS, Android or something else?  In general, it is very hard to know since every aspect of the environment in which an app runs could be faked.

Comment: There will be a website, an android app and an iOS app for the application. I did think it'd be a bit of a push to ensure that the user wasn't faking the GPS location on all of these platforms.